# SWRevealViewController always open on ipad

Tags: objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using swrevealviewcontroller on an iOS application. It's working perfectly with open and close style left menu but I have to get static opened left menu all the time on iPad.

I looked at documentation vs but the controller itself it's not well documented. I couldn't see any option on the

```
 [swrevealviewcontroller _initDefaultProperties]
```

method. I also tried FrontViewPosition s _initDefaultProperties but couldn't handle.

How can i create an always open menu on the iPad?

Comment: also want answer in swift plz